# How to import contacts using secure social 2.0.12 in scala Application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I am trying to import contacts from gmail in my scala application. I am using secure social.I can sign up using Google.But I want to retrive contacts of authenticated user.My application returns access token. But how to retrive contacts ?
The scope define is

```
scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting the token you need to make a WS.url call to the Google API to retrieve the data you need. You can do this from any SecuredAction.